# change color of specific label win32

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have a set of labels [8][8] each with it's own Id, from a routine I call to change label color giving the `hWnd`, but then nothing happens, but if i don't specify an Id on `case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:` all labels change color

```
DWORD WINAPI changecolor(LPVOID lpParameter){
clrLabelBkGnd = RGB(255, 255, 0x00);
            InvalidateRect(hWndLabel[0][0], NULL, TRUE);
return 0;
}
```

CALL back function

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
        ctrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);
    if (ctrlID == 1000) {
            hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
            SetBkColor(hdc, clrLabelBkGnd);
            return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(hBrushLabel);
        }
        else break;
```

main program

```
/* fill the labels IDs*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            labelId[i][j] = (i * 8 + j)+1000;
        }
    }
```

In this example when I specify id 1000 which exist `hWndLabel[0][0]` nothing is colored, but if I don't specify id or if i put `id > 1000` in  `case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:` all labels are colored even by calling only `hWndLabel[0][0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1000) {
            hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
```

Since `wParam` is the handle to the device context, why are you using it's low word as the ID of the control?

Take a look at [WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
wParam 
   Handle to the device context for the static control window.
lParam 
   Handle to the static control.
```

What you need to use is `lParam`.

```
DWORD ctrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam));
if (ctrlID == 1000)
{
}
```

**UPDATE**: Based on the comments you provided, you need to have a mechanism to retain the ID of the label that has been invalidated.

```
DWORD WINAPI changecolor(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    clrLabelBkGnd = RGB(255, 255, 0x00);
    someVariableToHoldLabelIdWithRightScope = labelId[0][0]; // Or GetDlgCtrlID(hWndLabel[0][0]);
    InvalidateRect(hWndLabel[0][0], NULL, TRUE);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, when you handle the color:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
    ctrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam);
    if (ctrlID == someVariableToHoldLabelIdWithRightScope)
    {
        hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
        SetBkColor(hdc, clrLabelBkGnd);
        return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(hBrushLabel);
    }
    else break;
```

If you invalidate more than one label at a time, then one variable like this is not enough. You need to have a list/array/queue of IDs.

Comment: I want to pass label identifier in `InvalidateRect(hWndLabel[0][0], NULL, TRUE);` called from outside function, and each time this fucntion is called, only the label with this id changes color

Comment: I think you have to store somewhere the ID of that label so that you can check it later from the handler for `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`.

Comment: yes I store it somewhere when I created the set of labels, but now as I said I have 64 labels, so to check with `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`should I use 64 case of ??

Comment: No. I had the impression you change one at a time. So store that ID somewhere and in the handler look for it.

Comment: sorry but I think this solution doest not work after all, I call `InvalidateRect(hWndLabel[0][0], NULL, TRUE);` outside the program, but when I check `DWORD ctrlID = GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam));
if (ctrlID == 1001)` which is not the id of hWndLabel[0][0], the label of id 1001 is colored  but I want only the label specified in `InvalidateRect` is colored ???

Answer (score 2):

Marius answered your question - you are misusing the parameters of `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`, which is why your painting is not working correctly.

I would suggest a different solution to your problem.  Have a list of colors, one set of Text/BkGnd colors for each label.  Make `changecolor()` update the color entries for just the specified label as needed and then invalidate that label to trigger a repaint.  `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` can then use the current colors of whichever label is currently being painted.  No need to keep track of the changed Control ID between the call to `changecolor()` and the triggering of `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` (doing so is error prone anyway - think of what would happen if you wanted to change another label's coloring before `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` of a previous change is processed).

I would suggest a `std::map` to associate each label `HWND` to a `struct` holding that label's colors, eg:

```
#include <map>

struct sLabelColors
{
    COLORREF clrText;
    COLORREF clrBkGnd;
    HBRUSH hBrushBkGnd;
};

std::map<HWND, sLabelColors> labelColors;
```

```
hWndLabel[0][0] = CreateWindowEx(...);
if (hWndLabel[0][0] != NULL)
{
    sLabelColors &colors = labelColors[hWndLabel[0][0]];
    colors.clrText = GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT);
    colors.clrBkGnd = GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW);
    colors.hBrushBkGnd = NULL;
}
```

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC: 
{
    HDC hdc = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);
    sLabelColors &colors = labelColors[(HWND)lParam];
    SetTextColor(hdc, colors.clrText);
    SetBkColor(hdc, colors.clrBkGnd);
    if (!colors.hBrushBkGnd) colors.hBrushBkGnd = CreateSolidBrush(colors.clrBkGnd);
    return reinterpret_cast<LRESULT>(colors.hBrushBkGnd);
}

case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
{
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == WM_DESTROY)
    {
        HWND hWnd = (HWND)lParam;
        std::map<HWND, sLabelColors>::iterator iter = labelColors.find((HWND)lParam);
        if (iter != labelColors.end())
        {
            if (iter->hBrushBkGnd) DeleteObject(iter->hBrushBkGnd);
            labelColors.erase(iter);
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

```
DWORD WINAPI changecolor(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    sLabelColors &colors = labelColors[hWndLabel[0][0]];

    if (colors.hBrushBkGnd) {
        DeleteObject(colors.hBrushBkGnd);
        colors.hBrushBkGnd = NULL;
    }

    colors.clrBkGnd = RGB(255, 255, 0x00);
    InvalidateRect(hWndLabel[0][0], NULL, TRUE);

    return 0;
}
```